# SASS/SCSS nest selector with parent

Tags: node.js, css, sass

in SCSS
we can do nest seletor like htis

```
div
    {
        &[id*='gemini-ad-']
        {
            @content;
        }
    }
```

will return `div[id*='gemini-ad-']`

but any way can make something like this?

```
[id*='gemini-ad-']
{
    div&
    {
        @content;
    }
}
```

return `div[id*='gemini-ad-']` too?

---

```
body:hover {}
a:hover {}
div:hover {}

:hover a {}
```

vs

```
:hover
{
    body& {}

    a& {}

    div& {}

    a {}
}
```

Comment: Do you just prefer the second form, or is there a reason that you can't use the first form to get the results you want in this case?

Comment: The simple answer to this question is "no" but I agree with @BenS that you need to provide the problem you are trying to solve so we can help.

Comment: @content may only be used within a mixin.

Comment: update: @BenS how about this demo, i prefer the second form

Comment: Sorry, I think @NathanielFlick is correct - I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want like this:

```
[id*='gemini-ad-']{
   @at-root div#{&}{
      /* CSS rules */
   }
 }
```

Outputs:

```
div[id*='gemini-ad-'] {
  /* CSS rules */
}
```